# Does a Heretic religion have a shorter holy war range?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm the King of Scotland and I control 100% of the British Isles. I'm a Lollard, and I used the Holy War CB to take control of the islands from the hands of the Catholics and the Norse. However, I can't declare a holy war against France just across the water.

Normally you can declare a holy war against someone with adjacent territory or across up to 2 sea zones. So, France should be in range, since we're touching the same sea zone. Is this a bug, or intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Holy War Casus Belli has the same range for all religions (except Jains and Unreformed Pagans who cannot use it). Your heresy is not the reason you cannot declare war.

This may be a bug or, more likely, there's something else stopping you.

Comment: Hmm, in the end I just fabricated a claim normally on the other side of the water and then did holy wars from there.